# List of variables from local scope

Tags: python, namespaces

In python `dir` displays all the names defined in namespace. I checked and it worked fine. 
But when I used `dir(function_name)` it didn't display the variables I created inside the function. Why?

Here's a code sample:

```
>>> def printHello(greetings):
...     inside_func=2
... 
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'printHello',]
>>> dir(printHello)
['__call__', '__class__', '__closure__', '__code__', '__defaults__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__get__', '__getattribute__', '__globals__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__name__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'func_closure', 'func_code', 'func_defaults', 'func_dict', 'func_doc', 'func_globals', 'func_name']
```

Comment: It would be better to open a book than to ask a question so early in your dev life...

Comment: From the documentation of [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir): "`dir([object])` Without arguments, return the list of names in the current local scope. With an argument, attempt to return a list of valid attributes for that object."

Comment: Use code block to display your code instead of screenshot, have a look at this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Comment: Because a local variable inside a function isn't an attribute of the function object. Also you've never called the function, so it's never actually existed.

Comment: Did you try [reading the docs for `dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir)?

Answer (score 0):

As to why `dir(youfunc)` doesn't list local vars, it's quite simply because as documented `dir(obj)` lists `obj`'s *attributes* , and local vars are not attributes of the function object.

Outside the function itself, you can get a listing of a function's local vars names with `yourfunc.func_code.co_varnames` (note that arguments are local variables):

```
def foo(bar):
    baaz = 42
print(foo.func_code.co_varnames)
```

but you won't obviously be able to access the local vars values from outside the function since those values only exist when the function is being executed.

From within the function you can get the local vars using `locals()`:

```
def foo(bar):
    baaz = 42
    print(locals())
```